# Google Spreadsheet: ImportXML from Google Drive .txt

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets

So, I'm a bit of a noob with this things, but I really need to get this working to reduce my daily workload.

**Goal:**

In google spreadsheet, extract the content of `.txt` files uploaded on a Google Drive folder into a cell.

I found an add-on for Google Spreadsheet that extracts the file and share link of all the files in a given Google Drive folder. It works fine and it should be the first step to automatize it.

With the URL, now I need to use `=ImportXML` to draw the data from the link into a cell.
It is a simple .txt file, here is a sample:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aS-AGcfs6nQYX3Mq6arm8K8BzuimAAES/view
Here is the element on the inspection view:
[drive-viewer-text-page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSLqe.png)
So far, the formula I tried is:

```
=importxml("https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aS-AGcfs6nQYX3Mq6arm8K8BzuimAAES/view?usp=sharing", "//body[text()='drive-viewer-text-page']/@*")
```

I also tried with `//div` and `//pre` instead of body, as well as inputting the whole path manually (the 10 divs included using a single "/").

So far, I keep getting the empty content message with "#N/A" on the cell.
I also tried with `//body[contains(text(), 'drive')]/@href` and `//body[contains(text(), 'drive')]/@*` with no positive results.

Any help is welcome, maybe I should start with a simpler task haha.

Thanks in advance.

Best regards,
Lucas.

**Edit:**
I am pretty sure the content of the file must be getting retrieved from some other URL, the viewer is not the direct URL to the file, but I can't seem to find it. Any help with that is also welcomed... and I'll need to automatize it too.

Comment: **UPDATE:**

The `=ImportXML` function works, but I often find empty cells as it takes a lot of time to load all the information from the links I need per month of work (around 110-120 files).
I'm looking into scripting now, it might be more efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this workaround? In this workaround, I used the direct link of the text file and IMPORTDATA().

In your case, the shared URL is as follows.

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aS-AGcfs6nQYX3Mq6arm8K8BzuimAAES/view?usp=sharing
```

When this is converted to the direct link, the URL becomes as follows.

```
http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1aS-AGcfs6nQYX3Mq6arm8K8BzuimAAES
```

This is used for IMPORTDATA().

I prepared 2 patterns because I'm not sure about the result what you want. For these 2 patterns, the above URL was put to "A1".

### Pattern 1 :

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(IMPORTDATA(A1)," "))
```

- Retrieve the values by IMPORTDATA().
- Split the values by .

Result :

[image]

### Pattern 2 :

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(IMPORTDATA(A1)," {2,}",","),","))
```

- Retrieve the values by IMPORTDATA().
- Replace the spaces more than 2 to `,` using REGEXREPLACE().
- Split the values by `,`.

Result :

[image]

### Note :

- If you want to import more complicated values, Google Apps Script might be suitable for the situation.

### References :

- [IMPORTDATA()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093335)
- [REGEXREPLACE()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. This was exactly what I was looking for and it worked like a charm.

Now I'm struggling to do the same with a .pdf file, I can import it just fine, but it has no shape or format with broken text and whatnot... The solution might be on regexreplace, but no luck so far. I'll look around for other cases of .pdf import.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Thanks again for the support. I'm not very well familiarized with the site yet. Answer accepted.
I'll post the new question a different thread... it seems like I'll have to get into scripts before I can solve this.

Comment: @Lucas Tonoli Thank you for your response. Also I would like to see your new question and think of the solution.